# About the time required to reboot the Update Management deployment schedule

Tags: azure, automation, azure-automation

I noticed that the time required for reboot is different between Docs and Portal.
Which is correct?

**Docs**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXwq.png)

**Portal**
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWudz.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's 15 minutes for Linux and 10 minutes for Windows. Will inform internal Azure Automation product team to update docs and portal comment as appropriate. Thanks.